# How do I combine data frames carrying information about multiple statistics across multiple variables and multiple groups?

Tags: r, correlation, p-value

I am calculating Spearman r values from mtcars correlations using this code:

```
 library(plyr)
 library(dplyr)
 mtcars[mtcars==3.440] <- NA
 mtcars[mtcars==4.22] <- NA
 mtcars[mtcars==18.90] <- NA
 selected <- select(mtcars, "cyl", "disp", "wt")
 mtcars$cyl <- as.factor(mtcars$cyl)
 for (i in "cyl") {
 co <- ddply(na.omit(selected), i, function(adf) cor(adf[,2], adf[,3], method ="spearman"))
   names(co) <- c('cyl',paste('CorCol',i, sep='_'))
   if(exists('odf')) { 
     odf <- merge(odf, co, by='cyl', all=TRUE)} else {
     odf <- co } }
 colnames(odf)[colnames(odf)=="CorCol_cyl"] <- "wt"
 selected <- select(mtcars, "cyl", "disp", "qsec")
 for (i in "cyl") {
 co <- ddply(na.omit(selected), i, function(adf) cor(adf[,2], adf[,3], method ="spearman"))
   names(co) <- c('cyl',paste('CorCol',i, sep='_'))
   if(exists('odf')) { 
     odf <- merge(odf, co, by='cyl', all=TRUE)} else {
     odf <- co } }
 colnames(odf)[colnames(odf)=="CorCol_cyl"] <- "qsec"
 selected <- select(mtcars, "cyl", "disp", "drat")
 for (i in "cyl") {
 co <- ddply(na.omit(selected), i, function(adf) cor(adf[,2], adf[,3], method ="spearman"))
   names(co) <- c('cyl',paste('CorCol',i, sep='_'))
   if(exists('odf')) { 
     odf <- merge(odf, co, by='cyl', all=TRUE)} else {
     odf <- co } }
 colnames(odf)[colnames(odf)=="CorCol_cyl"] <- "drat"
```

This results in this data frame with Spearman r values:

```
 > odf
     cyl  wt         qsec        drat
 1   4    0.8181818  0.29696970  -0.41337577
 2   6    0.7181848  0.92763366  -0.29629630
 3   8    0.4453704  0.07734925  -0.05153203
```

This is exactly what I wanted. However, I am interested in also generating two additional data frames, one is identical, but instead of the Spearman r values, it shows the Spearman p values. And another one is also identical, but instead it shows the sample sizes, i.e., the number of comparisons for each.

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose a [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) solution that makes use of list-columns (to work on all three `cyl` groups at once):

- I use `group_by()` to "loop" over the the three `cyl` groups instead of the explicit `for` loop.
- I use `cor.test`, which gives me the correlation and the p-value in one step. (Note, that I did not use Spearman correlation because of ties in the mtcars data set. You can adapt this to your needs with your actual data set.)
- The `cor.test()` goes inside `summarize()`, which reduces the data frame to one row (with the correlation etc.) for each unique value of `cyl`.
- I use `list()` inside `summarize()`, which creates the list-columns.
- I use `broom::tidy()` to nicely and consistently format the output of `cor.test()`.
- I `unnest()` the list-columns to get back an ordinary data frame without list-columns.
- The last `select()` just re-orders the columns in order to show the most relevant columns in the output below.

If you are unfamiliar with but interested in these tools, I suggest you take a look at the book R for Data Science, especially [Chapter 25 (Many Models)](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html).

```r
library("tidyverse")
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    summarize(n = n(),
              drat = list(cor.test(disp, drat, use = "pair")),
              wt   = list(cor.test(disp, wt,   use = "pair")),
              qsec = list(cor.test(disp, qsec, use = "pair"))) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(drat, wt, qsec), ~map(.x, ~broom::tidy(.x))) %>% 
    unnest(drat, wt, qsec, .sep = "_") %>% 
    select(cyl, n, ends_with("estimate"), ends_with("p.value"), everything())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 26
#>     cyl     n drat_estimate wt_estimate qsec_estimate drat_p.value
#>   <dbl> <int>         <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>        <dbl>
#> 1     4    11       -0.500        0.857         0.328       0.117 
#> 2     6     7       -0.831        0.473         0.789       0.0205
#> 3     8    14       -0.0922       0.755         0.195       0.754 
#> # ... with 20 more variables: wt_p.value <dbl>, qsec_p.value <dbl>,
#> #   drat_statistic <dbl>, drat_parameter <int>, drat_conf.low <dbl>,
#> #   drat_conf.high <dbl>, drat_method <chr>, drat_alternative <chr>,
#> #   wt_statistic <dbl>, wt_parameter <int>, wt_conf.low <dbl>,
#> #   wt_conf.high <dbl>, wt_method <chr>, wt_alternative <chr>,
#> #   qsec_statistic <dbl>, qsec_parameter <int>, qsec_conf.low <dbl>,
#> #   qsec_conf.high <dbl>, qsec_method <chr>, qsec_alternative <chr>
```

The first six rows could also be written as follows:

```r
mtcars %>% 
    add_count(cyl) %>% 
    group_by(cyl, n) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(drat, wt, qsec), ~list(cor.test(., disp)))
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for this efficient and detailed answer. I would give you 10 up-votes, if I could.

Comment: You are most welcome. You may think about editing the title of your question to make it more general and useful for others. Actually, the problems you faced are not specific to correlations. Maybe something along the lines of "How do I combine data frames carrying information about multiple statistics across multiple variables and multiple groups?"

Comment: Terrific! You are right. I changed the title accordingly. Thank you very much once again.